# Which Accessibililty event will get trigger when click back, home, menu buttons in android

Tags: android, android-hardware, accessibility

i tried to open the app and some accessibility events got triggered but when i click back or home or menu button in android devices i can't get any accessibility event. is this possible to get some event when clicking button. if it is normal apps i can get the clicks of a back or menu or home buttons click using on Pause method.  how can i get for Accessibility service class. please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can override onGesture(int gestureId) method in your Accessibility Service class to get the key events such as home event, back button event..

```
@Override
protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
    if(gestureId == GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Gesture Home Pressed");
    }
    return super.onGesture(gestureId);
}
```

For Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html